# Installing pip for pypy on a MacOs Sierra

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pypy, macos-high-sierra

I did a sudo easy-install pip which installed pip for python. However, I am unable to use it for pypy.

I did a ./pypy -m ensurepip which worked on another Mac (El Capitan) but not on the one I need to get working. The error I get is as such:

dyId: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/actlab/Downloads...../libpypy-c.dylib
Reason: Image not found
fish: './pypy -m ensurepip' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)

Any assistance would be highly appreciated! It is a major project and its due in March. I have been working on a personal pc all this while and now need it to run on the main server which has led to me all these error.

Comment: Use `pypy` installed with Homebrew (`brew install pypy`, or for `pypy3`, `brew install pypy3`), it already bundles pip. The executable is called `pip_pypy` or `pip_pypy3` for `pypy3`.

Comment: @hoefling thanks! that worked! however, when I try to install pyrebase (a database that I need to connect to) I am getting the following error:  

The target you are trying to run requires an OpenSSL implementation.

    Your system doesn't have one, and either the third_party directory
    doesn't have it, or your compiler can't build BoringSSL.  
I tried installing BoringSSL separately but that fails too. Any suggestions?